# Spring WebFlux + reactive DB2 - how to migrate from Hikari datasource and JDBC?

Tags: spring-boot, db2, spring-webflux

I've migrated an entire project to reactive WebFlux, the only missing thing is the DB queries. At the moment I'm using `JdbcTemplate` and Hikari Datasources and I need to make DB calls reactive?

I tried to use [vertx-db2-client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-db2-client/java/) but it seems it does not work fine with Webflux (or I'm not capable to use it correctly).

What options do I have? Can you show any working example with Webflux and DB2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to find that the database DB2 is supported by Spring data reactive libraries.  When I look at https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc I  don't see DB2 being in the list of database they support.

Comment: yes right, I saw that! What alternative do I have then?

Comment: It would seem we are SOL ...
Reason 1,000,001 to not Use DB2.